# What are the criminal penalties in Portugal for theft under 500.00?

Tags: theft, portugal

Does anyone know what the prison sentence is for theft in Portugal? Is it based on the value of the items?

Answer (score 1):

*Note I'm heavily relying on translation tools here, I do not speak Portuguese, nor was I generally familiar with Portuguese law before doing some quick research.*

Title II, Chapter II of the [Portuguese penal code](https://www.codigopenal.pt) defines property crimes. The lead Article 203 defines a baseline maximum of 3 years imprisonment or a fine (of unspecified quantity) for simple theft. The rest of the chapter essentially goes on to define specific cases or increased penalties for aggravating circumstances.

Note that Portuguese criminal law is very rehabilitation oriented rather than simply punitive and seems to give the judge wide discretion here. Title I, Chapter II (starting with Article 50) specifies that prison terms up to 3 years will likely be suspended (assuming the victim is compensated, the judge is satisfied there's no aggravating circumstances or likelihood of re-offending, there might be a fine imposed etc.).

Comment: A financial penalty without specification is generally 10 to 360 day-fines, actual cost of each unit being determined by the court based on the financial situation of the accused, but between 5 - 500 euros. (art. 47)